# Powershell Upload to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I've been trying to automate the process I usually have of uploading a file every morning from a folder into a SQL Server and I got a PowerShell script that would upload the file when I run the script working fine.

The problem is when I try to use the watcher feature in PowerShell I can get the console to tell me when changes are made to files in the folder the watcher is keeping an eye on but it won't then run my script that to upload the files within that folder to my SQL Server database.

The script to upload files to the SQL Server database is working when I run it separately but I cannot seem to get it to work with the watcher.

This script tells me when the files are changed and doesn't run the script action, however, it does run the action script when I press the "q" key to quit the script.

```
$folder = 'C:\Users\Example'
$filter = '*.csv'

# Create a new file system watcher
$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$watcher.Path = $folder
$watcher.Filter = $filter
$watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $false
$watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true

# Define the action to take when a file is changed
$action = {
    $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
    $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
    Write-Host "The file '$path' was $changeType at $(Get-Date)"

    # Run the BulkInsertScript.ps1 script
    & 'C:\Scripts\BulkInsertScript.ps1'
}

# Register the action to run when a file is changed
Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Changed" -Action $action -SourceIdentifier "Watcher"

# Wait for the user to press a key to quit (optional)
Write-Host "Press 'q' to quit the script."
do {
    $key = [System.Console]::ReadKey($true)
} until ($key.KeyChar -eq 'q')

# Unregister the event and dispose of the watcher object
Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier "Watcher"
$watcher.Dispose()
```

I have tried to change this to have a continuous loop so the script is constantly running but it doesn't run the action script at all when the watcher notices a change.

```
# Wait for changes to occur
while ($true) {
    # This loop keeps the script running so it can continue to monitor the folder for changes
}
```

Full Script

```
$folder = 'C:\Users\TDaly\Desktop\PowerShellTest'
$filter = '*.csv'

# Create a new file system watcher
$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$watcher.Path = $folder
$watcher.Filter = $filter
$watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $false
$watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true

# Define the action to take when a file is changed
$action = {
    $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
    $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
    Write-Host "The file '$path' was $changeType at $(Get-Date)"

    # Run the BulkInsertScript.ps1 script
    & 'C:\Scripts\BulkInsertScript.ps1'
}

# Register the action to run when a file is changed
Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Changed" -Action $action -SourceIdentifier "Watcher"

# Wait for the user to press a key to quit (optional)
Write-Host "Press 'q' to quit the script."
while($True) { 
if ([console]::KeyAvailable)
    {
        $key = [System.Console]::ReadKey() 
        if ($key.KeyChar -eq 'q')
        {
          break
        }
    } 
else
{
  Wait-Event -Timeout 1 #this waits but dont block the execution
}
}
# Unregister the event and dispose of the watcher object
Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier "Watcher"
$watcher.Dispose() 

# This is the script located at C:\Scripts\BulkInsertScript.ps1 that is trying to be called

# Set up connection string and SQL query
$connectionString = "Server=test;Database=ScriptTest;User Id=test;Password=example;"
$query = "BULK INSERT TestTable FROM 'C:\Users\TDaly\Desktop\PowerShellTest\Test.csv' WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n')"

# Create a SqlConnection object and open the connection
$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection($connectionString)
$connection.Open()

# Create a SqlCommand object and execute the query
$command = $connection.CreateCommand()
$command.CommandText = $query
$command.ExecuteNonQuery()

# Close the connection
$connection.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that powershell is single threaded, and System.Console::ReadKey blocks giving  your event code no chance to run.

You should change your loop to something like:

```
$folder = 'C:\Users\Sergey\Downloads\Posts'
$filter = '*.csv'

# Create a new file system watcher
$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$watcher.Path = $folder
$watcher.Filter = $filter
$watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $false
$watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true

# Define the action to take when a file is changed
$action = {
    $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
    $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
    Write-Host "The file '$path' was $changeType at $(Get-Date)"

    # Run the BulkInsertScript.ps1 script
    #& 'C:\Scripts\BulkInsertScript.ps1'
}

# Register the action to run when a file is changed
Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Changed" -Action $action -SourceIdentifier "Watcher"

# Wait for the user to press a key to quit (optional)
Write-Host "Press 'q' to quit the script."
while($True) { 
if ([console]::KeyAvailable)
    {
        $key = [System.Console]::ReadKey() 
        if ($key.KeyChar -eq 'q')
        {
          break
        }
    } 
else
{
  Wait-Event -Timeout 1 #this waits but dont block the execution
}
}
# Unregister the event and dispose of the watcher object
Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier "Watcher"
$watcher.Dispose()
```

Comment: I tried changing to loop according to the code you provided and I'm still running into the same issue where the console tells me a change has occurred but the script to upload into the SQL Server database doesn't seem to be running as there are no added rows in the database. The script to upload to the database runs fine separately so it isn't a server connection issue either.

Comment: worked fine for me. Well, i got the notiication that file was changed as soon as i changed it

Comment: posted whole script

Comment: So it successfully uploaded the data into an SQL Server database for you? I have absolutely no idea where mine is failing then.

Comment: Well I just added a dummy script that prints so it's being called. I suspect the problem is that you don't pass the file parameters anywhere

Comment: How would I go about fixing that? Apologies I'm insanely new to this.

Comment: If you post your bulk script, maybe i can see what the issue is

Comment: Ill edit the original post to include the whole script along with the script attempting to be called

Comment: your while loop doesn't contain the "Wait-Event" part. That's the key that allows powershell to process the events. Maybe that's the issue?

Comment: Apologies I pasted in the old code, the new code that was tested and still wouldn't run the script that includes the wait-event is in the original post now.

Comment: maybe the problem is that you are reusing same powershell window. close all the shell and start a new one. I used your bulk script as base and it worked. But one problem is that one edit to the file generated multiple bulk inserts. So this system has it's limitations :/

Comment: if you run just the bulk script, does that work?

Comment: Yeah the bulk script works itself! ah yeah I noticed sometimes when I changed the file the console would generate multiple "the file has changed" prompts so maybe this isn't the best way to go about it! Thanks for the help though!

Comment: the issue is that you have a race condition, how do you know when file is fully written. Ideally you should have the file writing process writing file and then starting the import process. or have a delayed import